# Hide and Show div's on Button Click in a UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, jquery, updatepanel

I am using UpdatePanel ---> LinkButton --> Div --->Table Structure.
When I click the Linkbutton the div has to show the table format first and has to execute the code in its OnClick event, the problem I am facing is I've tried so many jquery functions shown below:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnUnitAdd" runat="server" OnClientClick="Toggledivs()"  OnClick="lnkbtnAdd_Click" Text="Add" ></asp:LinkButton>
```

Even if I used:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{ 
    $("#lnkbtnUnitAdd").click(function () {
        $("#divUnit").show("slow"); return false;
    });
});
```

or

```
function Toggledivs()
{
    $("#lnkbtnUnitAdd").click(function () {
        $("#divUnit").show("slow"); return false;
    });
}
```

or without using the OnClientClick property in LinkButton

the result is same, as the function is returning false in button Onclient click or document.ready function(), therefore buttons Onclick event is not firing.

And if I comment the return false, the div is not showing up properly.

Please help how to deal as the whole process is running in an updatepanel.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use [**`Control.ClientID`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx) in this case. Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#<%=lnkbtnUnitAdd.ClientID%>").click(function () {
        $("#divUnit").show("slow"); return false;
    });
});
```

I won't recommend adding the event handler in HTML. But the following code should work. You don't have to assign the click event again.

```
function Toggledivs()
{
    $("#divUnit").show("slow"); 
    return false;
}
```

Give

```
return true;
```

if you want the `onclick` function to get executed.

Comment: This is where the real problem occured, as the function is returning false,i am not able to get into the OnClick event of that button "lnkbtnUnitAdd" in which i've written some server side code to disable and enable some controls

Comment: Instead of `return false;` give `return true;` so that the `onclick` function gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood what you meant, this should do it:
[__doPostBack](http://aspalliance.com/895_Understanding_the_JavaScript___doPostBack_Function.2) should be called only after the animation is done, you can do it by passing a callback function to jquery's show's, second parameter.
**UPDATES**:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{ 
    $("#lnkbtnUnitAdd").click(function (e) {
        var btnName = $(this).attr('name');           
        $("#divUnit").show("slow",function(){
           __doPostBack(btnName,''); //now call the actual postback event      
        });

        e.preventDefault(); //prevent default postback behavior
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Actually when myself digged in to my code, i found that my code structure looks like Updatepanle --->linkbutton---> UpdatePanel--->div tag, so when i am clicking the button the div tag which is set as display:none on page load is partially showing up and then going to default mode (something like toggling), do u have any idea how to overcome this problem

Comment: When i followed ur suggestion at first it didn't worked but later when i write the below code it worked, but the problem is function  Toggledivs() { 
    setTimeout(function() { alert('hi');
             
             $("#divUnit").show("slow");},0);
        }  but the problem is how to overcome the alert box

Comment: hey if u don't mind can u please go this page and download the attachment

http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread328075-3.html

as i am more concerned to solve this issue,

please kindly help, 

thanks in advance